# Unexpected dylib, la, and pc files with fresh mountain lion install

Tags: macos, homebrew

Just reinstalled osx and only installed chrome, sublime, and xcode cli tools so far. I got these warnings from brew doctor:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libmacfuse_i32.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libmacfuse_i64.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
  /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la
  /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc
```

Is it safe to remove these files or should I just ignore the warnings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you, by any chance, have `TrueCrypt` or `OSXFuse` installed? Because your problem looks like [this](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/15399) or [this](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14430). The TrueCrypt problem is fixed by [this script](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/5437061), and if you have OSXFuse, you can just remove it and use `homebrew`'s version instead.

Comment: The script fixed it. I used an encrypted flash drive to store files I wanted to keep, forgot to mention I installed TrueCrypt as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the answer @Bogdan gives (I upvoted it) but in case it doesn't work for anyone, [this script of mine](https://gist.github.com/SteveBenner/10938596) also provides a one-shot solution--just run it, and you're good.